# Why do WinVerifyTrust and sigcheck disagree about whether a file has a signature?

Tags: windows, code-signing

I've used the `WinVerifyTrust` example from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388208(VS.85).aspx), but I'm finding that it is getting a TRUST_E_NOSIGNATURE for some files that SysInternals `sigcheck` reports as signed.  For example, `c:\windows\system32\mfc42.dll` is reported by WinVerifyTrust as signed, but `c:\windows\system32\mfc42u.dll` is reported as unsigned -- sigcheck reports both as being signed.

I believe sigcheck is using WinVerifyTrust internally, but it must be using it differently than in the example I'm looking at -- any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this has to do with something called security catalog. Check out this example code: http://forum.sysinternals.com/howto-verify-the-digital-signature-of-a-file_topic19247.html